# 'These credentials do not authorize access' using Large Scale Matrix

Tags: here-api

I signed up for a 90 day free trial through an ADCi agent. I tried to use the Large Scale Matrix API, and successfully requested an authentication token using an OAuth1 signature. I was using the URL https://largescalematrix.router.hereapi.com/v1/matrix for the POST request. I received this error:

```
{'error': 'Forbidden', 'error_description': 'These credentials do not authorize access'}
```

My header of the request was:

```
headers = {
    'Authorization' : 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzUxMiIsImN0eSI6I...',
    'Content-Type' : 'application/json'
}
```

Do I need to be whitelisted to access this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Large-Scale Matrix Routing feature is excluded from Freemium and it is included with the Pro plan. for further details please contact [here](https://developer.here.com/help#how-can-we-help-you).

For more detail you can read this post with question number 8.

https://developer.here.com/faqs

Comment: Does that mean that a 90 day free trial does not allow a user to experiment with Large-Scale Matrix Routing? I thought the policy excluding this service only applied to Freemium.